# Parsing git log with readarray bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm parsing the output of "git log -1 --name-status" to grab the file extension for each file changed in the last commit. You can see a working example on http://goo.gl/Ms11a2

Once I got it working on tutorialspoint, I tried to run it in the git post-commit hook, but readarray line (#9) is throwing a syntax error.

> .git/hooks/post-commit: 9: .git/hooks/post-commit: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Can you guys point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong and why the heck is it working on http://goo.gl/Ms11a2 and not the post-commit? Excuse my ignorance... I don't have much experience with shell scripting.

```
#!/bin/sh
### git-stats hook (begin) ###
# Copy last commit hash to clipboard on commit
commit_hash=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
repo_url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
commit_date=$(git log -1 --format=%cd)
commit_changes=$(git log -1 --name-status)

readarray -t log_lines <<< "$commit_changes"
fileRegex='(.*)\.'
file_changed_start=6;
file_changed_line="${log_lines[file_changed_start]}"
declare -A languages;

# Step through each line that passes the regex
while  [[ "${file_changed_line}" =~ ${fileRegex} ]]; do
    # Store the file extension
    parsePathAndFilename="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    fileExtention=${file_changed_line#${parsePathAndFilename}};
    # Add 1 to the language that is already defined
    let languages[${fileExtention}]++;
    file_changed_start=$(($file_changed_start + 1))
    file_changed_line="${log_lines[file_changed_start]}"
done

# Create the JSON output
fileTypes="{";
fileTypeTotal=${#languages[@])};
assocKeys=(${!languages[@]});

for changed in "${!languages[@]}" 
    do
        if [[ "$changed" == "${assocKeys[fileTypeTotal-1]}" ]]
            then
                fileTypes+="\"$changed\" : ${languages[$changed]}";
            else
                fileTypes+="\"$changed\" : ${languages[$changed]},";
        fi
done

# close off the json
fileTypes+="}";

echo $fileTypes

commit_data="\"{ \"date\": \"$commit_date\", \"url\": \"$repo_url\", \"hash\": \"$commit_hash\", \"languages": \"$fileTypes\" }\""
git-stats --record "${commit_data}"
### git-stats hook (end) ###
```

Comment: What is the precise error message?

Comment: ".git/hooks/post-commit: 9: .git/hooks/post-commit: Syntax error: redirection unexpected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "here-string" syntax (`<<<`) is a bash extension; it is not present in basic shells. (It's not strictly bash; many other shells use it, too.) The same is true of arrays, and the `readarray` command.

So you need to make sure that you are using `bash` to run the script. Your shebang line (`#!/bin/sh`) tells the system to use a basic shell, and if the basic shell on your system is not bash, it may well not have `<<<`.

Try changing the shebang line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(Make sure that is the correct path to `bash`. You can verify with `which bash`.)